# Accessing item's view of adapter inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

Suppose my fragment consists of listview and each item consist of ImageView and TextView.My fragment has a button at bottom on click of which i want to change the image of ImagView of each list item in adapter.My imageview is in adapter and button is in fragment.How i access item's view of adapter inside fragment?

Comment: get the position from listview and access element that position

Comment: @Mohit i want to access a particular view of the element at that position(or all the positions)..

Comment: @Mohit Button is not part of listview

Comment: so provide the perticuler position value you want to access...

Comment: @Mohit okay..if i want to access imageview of position 1

Comment: What type is mUserList ? If it has a custom class object post the model.

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar What do model have to do with my issue or problem..?

Comment: How do you set image in  viewHolder.typeimage ?

Comment: @Mohit i want to access  `viewHolder.typeimage` and change the image of that imageview from fragemnt on ckick of button..i don't want to access complete element..

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar viewHolder.typeimage.setImageResource()..

Comment: put the condition for position you want in `getView`

Comment: @Mohit think wht i am saying..u r still not getting the issue..

Comment: in my case i need to change textview color when in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Still unclear but try this:
First pass the image id while creating the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new ConnectAdapter(mUserList,R.drawable.test);
```

**ConnectAdapter**

```
private image;
ConnectAdapter(List<> mUserList,int imageID){
this.image = imageID;
}
public setImageID(int imageID){
this.image = imageID;
}
if (convertView == null) {  
. 
. 
. 
viewHolder.typeimage.setImageResource(image);
}
```

**Fragment**

```
 mAdapter = new ConnectAdapter(mUserList); 
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
      followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onClick(View v) {
mAdapter.setImageID(YOURIMAGEID);
mAdapter.notifyDatasetCHanged();
                                               } 
                            } 
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access view of adapter inside fragment with interface as follows:

In your ConnectAdapter declare an interface as follows:

```
public interface ViewClickListener {

    void onViewClick(View view);
}
```

write as instance variable in adapter for ViewClickListener as follows:

```
private ViewClickListener listener;
```

In your fragment instantiate as follows:

```
mAdapter = new ConnectAdapter(mUserList,new ConnectAdapter.ViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewClick(View view) {
        // do what you want with view

        }
    });
```

in your adapter's getView() method write onclick listener on view as follows:

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onViewClick(convertView);
        }
    });
```

so after view click you will get callback in fragment.Hope it helps